# SneakyThrows is not working for BeanUtils.copyProperties

Tags: java, lombok

I have this method:

```
@SneakyThrows
    protected void process(){
 BeanUtils.copyProperties(A, B);
}
```

and it is not compiling, it is like SneakyThrows would not work for BeanUtils method, Lombok 1.18.16

```
Error:(118, 45) java: unreported exception java.lang.IllegalAccessException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

Do u know what would be solution for this?

Comment: What ends up compiling this? `javac` on the command line? mvn? eclipse?

Comment: Add annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombok_version}"